# Joining four tables but excluding duplicates

Tags: join, no-duplicates

I am trying to join four tables (users, user_payments, content_type and media_content) but I always get duplicates. Instead of seeing for example that user Smith purchased media_content_id_purchase 5011 for a price of 3.99 and he streamed media_content_stream_id 5000 for a price of 0.001 per min, I get:

multiple combinations such as, media_content_id_purchase 5011 costs 3.99, 1.99, 6.99 etc. with media_content_id_stream that also has all sorts of prices.

This is my query:

```
select u.surname, up.media_content_id_purchase, ct.purchase_price,  up.media_content_id_stream, ct.stream_price, ct.min_price

from users u, user_payments up, content_type ct, media_content mc

where u.user_ID=up.user_ID_purchase and 
up.media_content_ID_purchase=mc.media_content_ID or up.media_content_ID_purchase is null and
ct.content_type_ID=mc.content_type_ID;
```

My goal is to display each user and what they have consumed with the corresponding prices.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should try using `select distinct`?

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

As you can see here select DISTINCT is supposed to show only the different (distinct) values.